# How can I change the homepage in Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I need to change home page, push new html code with its styles instead of current home page (Electronic store). How to do that? What jsp or tag files I need to edit, because I cant find it. Thanks!

I tried finding what HomeController returns, but I couldn't find exactly where I can edit html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hybris has WCMS for managing pages. So you cannot a find single jsp file for a page. You need to learn hybris basics first.

You can start form here: https://www.stackextend.com/hybris/everything-about-wcms-in-hybris/